# Как использовать ajax в ASP .NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

На главной странице есть

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Period,
                      SelectListItemsSource.NalogPeriodList, 
                      new { @id = "nalog_period" })
```

Необходимо при событии onchange вызывать метод действия

```
public PartialViewResult ShowInvoicesDetails(string period)
```

Это делается с помощью ajax, или какими-то стандартными методами?

Comment: да, это деляется с помощью ajax абсолютно так же как и в случае с другими технологиями - клиентский  js для всех один по большому счету

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть 2 варианта:

1.Использовать асинхронную форму. В представлении указываете `id` элемента, который необходимо обновлять

```
AjaxOptions ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "tableBody"
};
```

Здесь же можно указать дополнительные параметры. Затем помещаете ваш выпадающий список в форму

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("ShowInvoicesDetails", ajaxOptions))
{
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Period,
                             SelectListItemsSource.NalogPeriodList, 
                             new { @id = "nalog_period",
                                   onchange = "$(this.form).submit();" })
    </div>
}
```

При событии выбора элемента будет выполняться запрос и обновляться содержимое элемента `tableBody`

2.Самому написать обработчик события на JavaScript и для отправки запроса использовать `$.ajax();`, затем изменять содержимое нового элемента пришедшими данными в обработчике события `success`